# Question regarding my compiler for C++ visual studio code MingGW (brand new to coding)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, compilation, mingw-w64

I recently installed mingw-64 for my coding stuff since I am very new and trying to learn c++ on my freetime. I did all of the steps that they told me to do in order to start my first "hello world" program and I am getting errors when I try to run it. Did I mess up my pathing? I followed these steps https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_add-the-mingw-compiler-to-your-path

[image: The error that pops up]

Comment: For some reason your code (+ executable) is located in the `.vscode`-folder. You are simply using the wrong path. Move all the files one folder up so they actually sit in the `My Code`-Folder.

Comment: Did you consider installing [Debian](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on your computer, and using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`?

Comment: For beginners visual studio is much easier to setup than vs code

Answer (score 1):

The command `./helloworld` is a unix specific command, just type helloworld.exe and make sure you're in the directory of your build file.

Comment: They're using powesrshell so `.\helloworld` is actually correct and a forward slash should work too I think. Powesrshell requires a full path so `helloworld` or `helloworld.exe` won't work

Answer (score 1):

You are simply using wrong folder to keep your file !!
just move out of the .vscode folder and make your file in the "My code" folder.

Comment: _"Assuming [...] , and that you saved your helloworld.cpp file in the same directory(folder)"_ - that's not the case as you can see on the picture. And concerning _"VS Code has a slightly different set of commands to execute C++ programs"_ - the command you provided does exactly that. Compile code to executable, then run that executable.

Comment: .. that's not the case as you can see on the picture ...
Yes !  Exactly you are right , he should move one folder up & write code in the  "My Code" folder .